# Invalid path to html file in appinfo.json

Tags: webos

I am trying to debug my webos app in webos ide.When I click on debug button it says `Errors found in appinfo.json file while parsing.` This is my appinfo.json
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUXla.png)

I think the issue is how I have entered the path to my html file. The path is `'/App/index.html'`. Please let me know if you know how can I type the path in correct format

Comment: Strange. I tried it and it does not seem to take capital letters or / in the property main. Works with having the index.html in root folder of the project though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you must specify the path as a relative path to your html file (App/index.html) not as an absolute path

You can check other app.json properties at [here](https://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/app-developer-guide/app-metadata/)

I can't add the whole json to the comment, please check this one (a free sample of a basic HTML app that you can find at [webostv.developer.lge.com/](https://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/code-samples/basic-html-app/))

```
{
    "id": "com.lgdev.hello-world",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "uiRevision": 2,
    "vendor": "LG Developer",
    "type": "web",
    "main": "index.html",
    "title": "Hello World",
    "appDescription": "Hello World",
    "icon": "icon.png",
    "largeIcon": "largeIcon.png",
    "iconColor": "blue",
    "bgColor": "white",
    "splashBackground": "app_bg_1920x1080.png",
    "bgImage": "app_bg2_1920x1080.png"
}
```

If you need to move your index.html for example to 'myappfolder' folder you must modify your appinfo.json to the correct relative path 'myappfolder/index.html'

Comment: thanks for the reply! can you show me an example how can I write relative path in json file? I am not able to understand from that link.

Comment: Please check some basic samples to build a web app at https://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/code-samples/basic-html-app/ 

And follow the development basics like https://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/app-developer-guide/app-metadata/ where you can find "The file path must be relative to the appinfo.json file and needs to point to an HTML file. The default is index.html"

At your sample the 'mail' should be 'App/index.html' without the first '/' that means the system will try to get your index file from the root of the filesytem...